# What copyright license are the Badge images under?

Tags: discussion, badges

I am working on a [desktop application](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments) that displays information about what badges a user has earned from AskUbuntu.com, and we would like to display them using the same badge images (though scaled to a larger size) as they have on AskUbuntu.  Are the images currently using a CC license, or could they be provided under a CC license, so that they could be used in and distributed with this open source application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sorry, but using those images in your software would not be appropriate.

**Only the user-contributed content** is covered under the Create Commons license. The logos and other site elements are copyrighted. Be careful, because some of the elements of this site have also been licensed to us by Canonical and are protected.

Please see our [**Trademark Guidance**](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) for a more thorough discussion about how to use elements of this site.

Comment: "...some of the elements of this site have also been licensed to us by Canonical..." Well, that won't be a problem. The user asking this question works for Canonical :)

Comment: Yes, but the project isn't a Canonical project, so I'd still need to get approval to use them.

Comment: Even then, the images for the software here on Stack Exchange may not even be in Canonical's purview.  Only the Canonical-owned imagery (if approved) could be used.

Answer (score -1):

I used the Gimp to upscale the badge image and then traced a path:

[image]

I then tried some of the reverse image search engines:

- **Google Image Search** - [some results, but no badge](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitTJnmbJsc9jAPs5pwOl-w6o78qvaLjtXZ1nBnYk-7K86xLrRe7oj69LYktNrKOIhTqA6X_1Ovap2vdynBOGFAL6LGDdTEUIuLAe2RFTexDfg-5w7RrBNoI_1wj4WuhtOjhTdKPw7u-C7b74fnWix3iT4iFBsEiyRQdjL4c6tEDNylt3pYpVa73vFu11Izm8ctA00bKTzfyK70VatJ98672GSKvCrykXIbLXXIkEQu5pGnMV-SSHk8ymMAFrj0x9yYJzXCIdwcP4Z0SLpqexvVy6DLufZI4ESznSa1OkrV2GXW5esxoqRqp6DWfXp7MrIe3zYoFMXlrXaWiuofpavuwthML98Us6aAmg1s8m-xpzV52N3R6lJOE6JU0VwHqOs9pJAY9xgxrhfJJ5zgmiIbfan7oCdGJYCg8a_1rBd19C20kOXBKtRdnLJPe5q9wBfLj8LN8wwPoWQ_1kHgSanPlC8MzfkQdwneZAhbPvUN1vLmJVxNltJ_1lpVd9QUMELxz3CJMXr_1eIJK6OcCBAyl_1dJlOUzmoyd869Xqx2B5966Ij9iFuV5hr2giqKV3JA9x3ywjSAAXTILfprdAkyUdULp7d1NBDTISjRd-XzFRop8MLaZeQkLrAO0QtUSnaCgYNjNknCff1CnAJdcGQEeQBIKkbzYT2exY0tFTGXDUnQ7s_1XG7_1zqTwEmJaL8L3s4-QD5QcNzw4jIgdnyPcpmSpeTr2_13eczqsJjRi25hLq3LAPCRII31xpBR9IgJy_1SZ9Ab6RBrqrDcqE1Fiucj8LDNhZFWQpIUeVIUCRklPnKCu6kAlfYYVIhZdyS_1aSuNCBc225sJWki2hF6gj5_1Ji66IRqjZH-Be_1kAcREmzWjOYs8ShP8mxT-R5PGl4YB0aw3rAtyWhwvnPP13c55_1v3QkL0JX9ClB9ntbldFWN6WNth1OPRto60oCH7hyMLuCpQclThE54S9azruCU4C0RndC-54tLVhj_1TiDiNx0Uq-9pFfqsmGKq9t3ugxvrZpidLwSvRz82GsdUsyxNe8H7Axrk3bg-hWpp6C7c9pKva4auZe1CoUJpHnrOWIe4GqN1ZRvMs2BfJTEF3GvByuhIBswZOyFBukPS9RSKdXGhrZAb9nZCgNEqyzDoXDkGmNrnlKK6vKEl4VUqamyi02C8Omo_1S-d6vLAPMQ&num=10&hl=en&bih=655&biw=1280)
- **Tin Eye** - [no results](http://tineye.com/search/bb259e2425091190b1e9d088154c166e541470d7/).

All of that being said, the bottom of each pages states:

> "site design / logo © 2012 stack exchange inc"

Comment: Whoah... why are people downvoting this answer? I took time out of my day to try and track down the origin of the badge images!

Comment: Erm... The circle should be perfectly round as per http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntumeta/img/sprites.png?v=2

Comment: I did'nt downvoted, but this badge looks ugly.

Comment: It's not supposed to be something you can use - it's just enough of the original image to capture the shape and use it in a reverse image search.

Comment: I understand you may have put some effort into this, but it really doesn't address the question that was asked.

Comment: Hmmm..  the reverse image search on that either results in this question or the canadian flag (due to the 'jaggedness' of it). making it round eventually results in http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/12151/178596