# Is Ask Ubuntu boring?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I visit other SE sites, they always have very cool features and fun things with our site seems to lack. Can we try to make this site more fun?

**What Other Sites Have:**

- Fancy Chat names (like "The Bridge) -- All we have is "Ask Ubuntu General Room".
- Fancy Chat pings -- Our ping is pretty generic IMO
- Fancy Badge logos -- Go over to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) or [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/). They have really nice badge logos. We only have a dot.
- Nice Fonts -- Every site seems to use their own font in the headers. Why do we not use the "Ubuntu" font?

**What We Have:**

- An awesome user-base, ready to answer almost any and all questions.

For instance, why don't we make our badges little colored Ubuntu logos? Why don't we have a nicer chat name, like "The Root Shell"? Why not a nicer ping (maybe less harsh)?

Comment: Pretty sure we have the same ping sound as any other site on SE chat... (note that SO and MSE aren't on SE chat, they have their own respective chat networks)

Comment: I think you mean "The Sudo Room". :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our badges are customized based on the Ubuntu pictograms, specifically the "certification" one:

http://design.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/pictogram-certification-orange-hex.svg

[image]

As for the chat rooms, when you have the privilege you can make your own "Fancy" chat room. Examples of "fun" ones in the past:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8261
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8349
http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3844

Otherwise most of the fun action actually goes on in the general room.

Comment: I did not know that.

Answer (score 4):

> Nice Fonts -- Every site seems to use their own font in the headers. Why do we not use the "Ubuntu" font?

We do:

[image]

Comment: Huh. It doesn't look like the Ubuntu font to me. */me goes to play withe Firefox insides*

Comment: It's also being linked in as a webfont if you don't already have it installed.